# Credit card data - sharing and storage

Tags: encryption, credit-card

What is the industry standard for sharing credit card data between client (thin & thick) and server?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the [PCI-DSS](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/pci_dss_v2.pdf)

Comment: @JohnDowney - you should turn that into an answer.  I'm sure that would be an easy one to flush out.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why he didn't put it as an answer, but John Downey is correct, the [PCI-DSS](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/) is what you are looking for.  It is the industry standard for protection of PCI (credit card details) in transit and at rest (in storage).